# Avoid Postback on command field

Tags: asp.net

I have a commandfiled inside my gridview.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true"  ShowDeleteButton="true"  
                EditImageUrl="~/Icons/1414412214_edit.png" EditText="Edit" 
                DeleteImageUrl="~/Icons/1414412198_delete.png" UpdateText="Done"   >
            <ItemStyle Height="10%" Width="10%" />
            </asp:CommandField>
```

How can I stop post back on edit link button and still be able to show the update and cancel link on clicking it. I know that I can do that using update panel and I tried it did not work?

Answer (score 1):

use update panel to avoid full page postback.. or try any jquery grid plugin in your application.
[Using JqGrid in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609442/Using-JqGrid-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: Bhavik How could this be done using update panel since I tried to place my command field inside update panel but it did not work.If u got some time then please guide me how to use update panel here?

Comment: You can assign Postback Trigger have look this article http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Assign-PostBack-Trigger-Full-PostBack-for-LinkButton-inside-GridView-within-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ASPNet.aspx